# latin characters are incorrectly interpreted when sent to sever

Tags: java, character-encoding, internationalization

My application is multi-lingual support. There are some Spanish users who are typing some Latin characters in textboxes / textareas like á, é, í, ó, ú, ü, ñ, ¿, ¡

I have tried adding page-encoding

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%> 

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

But still it is displaying incorrectly when sent to server and displayed.

Eg. User is typing **comunicación** but in database it is stored as **comunicaciÃ³n**

Comment: You have a character encoding problem - somewhere in your code, something is converting bytes to characters using the wrong character encoding. It's very hard to say where exactly the problem is - this can be in many places: when sending data to the server, when storing it in the database, when retrieving it from the db, when displaying it, ... (where and how exactly are you displaying the text?). In Java, be especially aware of methods such as `String.getBytes()` which use the default char encoding of your system, which may not be what you need.

Comment: What is the data type and collation of the database column? And what code retrieves and displays it?

Comment: @Tom Blodget its NVARCHAR - AL32UTF8

Comment: Try to divide and conquer. Can you use Fiddler or Wireshark to see the bytes sent by the web browser to the web server? How are you retrieving and displaying the value from the database? Can you store comunicación there by other means and display it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was encoding issue.Somehow encoding was changed. I have added encoding filter. It works properly.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
       <param-name>encoding</param-name>
       <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
       <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
       <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
       <filter-name>encoding-filter</filter-name>
       <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```